# file_exist function won't work

Tags: php

I have a function that checks if the mobile image exists and if does then it will return true. No matter what I do I can't get this function to work properly.

```
public function mobileImageExist($image)
{
    $file = "images/$image";
    if(file_exists($file))
        return true;

    return false;
}
```

I have also tried

```
public function mobileImageExist($image)
{
    $file = dirname(__FILE__)."/images/$image";
    if(file_exists($file))
        return true;

    return false;
}
```

the $image parameter that is being passed to the function is just the image name. ex: banner_mobile.jpg

Comment: That's because it is doing its job and telling you the file doesn't exist.

Comment: Nobody has a problem with this function but you. My money is on *the file simply isn't there*.

Comment: I imagine your file path is just wrong.

Comment: Or the path.  What is `echo dirname(__FILE__)."/images/$image";`?  Is that an actual file?

Comment: Verify `$image` contains what you expect it to, and consequently that `$file` contains what you expect, via `var_dump($image);`

Comment: Either `$image` has wrong data or the directory is incorrect, the code is 100% right !

Comment: It will return true no matter what for me. Even if I rename the image in the directory and don't change it in the code. It still returns true

Comment: i know its not required but ... `if(file_exists($file)){return true;}else{ return false;}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working. It ended up being another function that was referencing the mobileImageExist function and causing it to somehow return true whether or not the file existed or not